# If no item selected then prevent user from click the floating button

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

How can I force a user to first select before they can click the floating button?  If nothing is selected, then when the the floating button is clicked it will display "Please select a subject."

Here's what I have so far:

```
if(spinnerM.getSelectedItem() != null) {
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonAddMark);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

       @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent add = new Intent(AddMark.this, AddMarkInside.class);
            startActivity(add);
        }
    });
}
else {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please select a subject", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: problem solved. Thanks for spending the time for those who view this post.

Answer (score 0):

Create a boolean variable and make it true when user selects any item from spinner and in your fab on click listener check whether that boolean is true or not. If not show a toast message to the user.

Comment: i solved it already Just the arrangement of the code put wrongly. Thanks anyway